# WordPress API : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am using WordPress API and I got a problem is that:

If an user is already signed in by normal way.

Then they use API to login and use token to post comment. It appears an problem with message like bottom:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
```

If user is not already signed in by normal way then it is ok to post comment with token login via API

Can you explain me why?

Comment: Check this out https://v2.wp-api.org/guide/authentication/

Comment: @SagarTamang. I use token as login method. So I want disable login by X-WP-Nonce. Can you suggest me ? Thank you so much

Comment: As far as I know, when a user is logged in by wp-admin, the session is created. But when you need to perform some operation via REST API, you need some type of authentication to measure and token to identify individual user.